# Get Total Page Count in RDLC from code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am trying to get the total number of pages of a report after it was rendered.

Tried the following, both didn't work.

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.GetTotalPages();
ReportViewer.ServerReport.GetTotalPages();
```

Sample Code:

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource(myDatasource);
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

//render PDf file
byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType,      out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
//NEED THE TOTAL PAGES HERE ???
return bytes;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use signatures in your posts. Editted.

Answer (score 0):

I use local report and setting `PageCountMode=Actual` does not solve my problem.

But when I press `PrintLayout` toggle button on toolbar it shows me all of my pages at once. So I set this layout initially instead of `PrintLayout` like this:

```
RptViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.Normal);
```

And of-course you can always switch back to `PrintLayout`.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply give this in the RDLC design and you can get the number of pages generated.please give this in the expression.

**=Globals!TotalPages**